# Start service on boot after another service

Tags: linux, service

How can I start a Linux service after another service on boot.
For example:

- first I want to start myscript.service
- after that I want to start dhcpcd.service

Comment: maybe this will be of help https://serverfault.com/questions/176055/how-to-change-linux-services-startup-boot-order

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.